# extjs grid inside add multiple control in single column with different control

Tags: extjs

extjs grid inside single column inside different control display.
grid render this time control render not cell edit this time control display this my not requirment.

my requirement is grid data load this time display control.

example.

```
 xtype: 'grid',
                margin: '0 0 8 0',
                itemId: 'navigationgrid',
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    clicksToEdit: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        beforeedit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                            if (context.colIdx == 1 && context.record.get('functionality') == "DocumentReviewAudit_edit") {
                                return false;

                            } else {
                                return false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                flex: 1,
                store: {
                    fields: ['allowed', 'functionality', 'dis_functionality'],
                    data: [
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Case Folders', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.caseFolderNavigationFunctionality },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'User Folders', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.workFolderNavigationFunctionality },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Review Folders', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.userFolderNavigationFunctionality },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Production Folders', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.productionFunctionality },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Case Clusters', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.caseLevelClusterFunctionality },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Key Phrases & Doc Summary', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.keyPhreasesAndDocSummary },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Document Review Audit', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.documentReviewAudit },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'DocumentReviewAudit_edit', dis_functionality: ''},
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Duplicate Document Info', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.duplicateDocumentInfo },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'View E-Mail Threads', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.viewEmailThreads },
                        { allowed: me.isCreateUser, functionality: 'Work Product', dis_functionality: LAN.userFunctionality.workProductFunctionality }
                    ]
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'CheckboxHeaderColumn',
                        dataIndex: 'allowed',
                        hideable: false,
                        sortable: false,
                        width: 25,
                        disabled: me.isReadOnly,
                        listeners: {
                            checkchange: function (column, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
                                var navigationgrid = me.down('#navigationgrid'),
                                    record = navigationgrid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                if (record) {
                                    record.set('allowed', checked);
                                    record.commit();
                                    navigationgrid.getStore().sync();
                                }
                            },
                            headerclick: Ext.bind(me.headerClick, this, me, true)
                        }
                    },
                     {
                         text: LAN.users.viewOptions,
                         dataIndex: 'dis_functionality',
                         flex: 3,
                         hideable: false,
                         sortable: false,
                         editor: 'textfield'
                     },
                    {
                        text: LAN.users.viewOptions,
                        dataIndex: 'functionality',
                        flex: 3,
                        //hideable: false,
                        hidden: true,
                        sortable: false
                    }

                ],
                listeners: {
                    //    cellclick: function (ctrl, gridCell, index, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
                    //        me.cellClick(ctrl, gridCell, index, record, tr, rowIndex, e);
                    //    }

                    select: function () {
                        me.down('#navigationgrid').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                    },                    
                }
```

Comment: Can you please ellaborate your question more? not able to understand the question

Comment: extjs grid inside single column inside different controll for example
first cell inside lebale second cell inside textbox ext.

Comment: all are different controls? or only texbox and label particularly? i mean specific number of TYPE of controls to show in grid?